# why the keyboard in the bot are not working?

Tags: python, aiogram, pyrogram

The bot sends me a screenshot message with promo code activation, and 4 buttons are created under the message, namely 1-4, and each button executes its own script in Chromium, but for some reason the buttons are not working from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait as WB
from pyrogram import Client, types, filters
from pyrogram.handlers import MessageHandler, callback_query_handler
from aiogram import Bot
import shutil
import subprocess
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
import requests
import os
import re
import time
import logging

```
def get_id_session(app: Client):
#doesnt matter


def init_driver(headless: bool):
#doesnt matter


def get_domen():
#doesnt matter


def open_web_site(driver: uc.Chrome):
#doesnt matter






 async def send_notify(promocode: str, result: float, balance: int):
#keybo
    reply_markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup([
        [
            types.InlineKeyboardButton("Button 1", callback_data="0"),
            types.InlineKeyboardButton("Button 2", callback_data="1"),
        ],
        [
            types.InlineKeyboardButton("Button 3", callback_data="2"),
            types.InlineKeyboardButton("Button 4", callback_data="3"),
        ],
    ])

    await bot.send_photo(
        chat_id=sender_id,
        photo=open('temp.png', 'rb'),
        caption=f'Activation statistics :\n\n'
                f'*Total activation time : *{result}'
                f'*Actual balance : *{balance}',
        parse_mode='Markdown',
        reply_markup=reply_markup
    )
    os.remove('temp.png')

#handler
async def button_handler(client: Client, callback_query: types.CallbackQuery):
    button_id = int(callback_query.data)
    logging.info(f'A button with a number is pressed {button_id}')
    if button_id == 0:
        driver.execute_script('document.querySelectorAll("div.captcha__variants > button")[0].click()')
    elif button_id == 1:
        driver.execute_script('document.querySelectorAll("div.captcha__variants > button")[1].click()')
    elif button_id == 2:
        driver.execute_script('document.querySelectorAll("div.captcha__variants > button")[2].click()')
    elif button_id == 3:
        driver.execute_script('document.querySelectorAll("div.captcha__variants > button")[3].click()')
    elif button_id == 4:
        driver.execute_script('document.querySelectorAll("div.captcha__variants > button")[3].click()')    
    await callback_query.answer()


def activate_promocode(promocode: str, driver: uc.Chrome):
#doesn't matter



async def get_promo_handler(client: Client, message: types.Message):
#doesn't matter



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Меню:\n1. Run the script.\n2. Account authorization.\n3. Clear the script cache.\n4. End all script processes.')
    _func = input('\nEnter the function you need - ')

    subprocess.call('taskkill /f /im chrome.exe', stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)
    subprocess.call('taskkill /f /im undetected_chromedriver.exe', stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL, stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL)

    if _func == '1':
        baza_promocode = []
        driver = init_driver(False)
        open_web_site(driver)
        channels = [-100184339344, -1001348070579, -1001686106961, -1001680254374]


        try:
            with open("files\\channels.txt", "r", encoding='utf8') as f:
                if read := f.read():
                    for channel in read.strip().split('\n'):
                        channels.append(int(channel))

        except FileNotFoundError:
            open('files\\channels.txt', 'w').close()

        app = Client("files\\session", api_id=#doesn't matter, api_hash='#doesn't matter')
        bot = Bot(bytes(
            [54, 51, 15, 65, 70, 90, 90, 115, 82, 118, 76, 111, 122, 113, 75, 95, 118,
              69, 76, 112, 111, 95, 114, 103, 48, 112, 45, 78, 87, 102, 95, 71, 115, 67, 53, 110, 107]).decode())
        with app:
            sender_id = get_id_session(app)

        app.add_handler(MessageHandler(get_promo_handler, filters=filters.chat(list(map(int, channels)))))
        app.add_handler(lambda client, callback_query: callback_query_handler(client, callback_query, button_handler))
        print('Detected authorization, launched successfully.')
        app.run()

    if _func == '2':
    #doesn't matter


    if _func == '3':
    #doesn't matter


    if _func == '4':
    #doesn't matter

    input('\nExit')
```

i tried different ways to fix this trouble